# Index matrix based on another matrix of start and end indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Consider a 1D array: y(1:20) and a collection of indices in a matrix form: indx = [1,3;7,12;16,19]

Is there a neat way to get a cell array: {y(1:3), y(7:12), y(16:19)} ?

It is easily done with loops, but I'm curios to know a simple and a cleaner way to pass a collection of indices to 1D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way around using loops. You can use `arrayfun` as a shorthand though:

```
arrayfun(@(from,to) y(from:to), indx(:,1), indx(:,2), 'uni', 0)
```

running this on your data results in

```
y = (1:20)*10;
indx = [1,3;7,12;16,19];

celldisp(arrayfun(@(from,to) y(from:to), indx(:,1), indx(:,2), 'uni', 0))

ans{1} =

    10    20    30



ans{2} =

    70    80    90   100   110   120



ans{3} =

   160   170   180   190
```

Comment: Maybe more readable: `arrayfun(@(from,to) y(from:to), indx(:,1), indx(:,2), 'uni', 0)`

Comment: @ArnoldKlein just know that if anything, this is probably less run-time efficient than a simple for-loop as `arrayfun` just performs a loop under the hood.

Comment: @Dan, Thanks, good to know. I am learning the "matlabian" way to code, so I'm trying to avoid any loops or "quick and dirty" implementation.